# How can I use multiple Datatables on my CrystalReport?

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports, dataset

I have a dataset that connects with three databases. How can I attach my Crystalreport viewer so all three are included?

[image]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument X = new ReportDocument();
            DataTable DTable = new DataTable();

            DataSet1TableAdapters.TableAdapterManager ????? = new WebApplication1.DataSet1TableAdapters.TableAdapterManager();

            DTable = ????????

            string ubicacion = Server.MapPath("crystalReport1.rpt");
            X.Load(ubicacion);
            X.SetDataSource(DTable);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = X;
        }
```

Comment: Ah, welcome to the pain of Crystal Reports!

Comment: I don't see how it'd be any less painful in SSRS, dealing with multiple databases

Comment: I donno if I am right but subreports can help you in Crystal reports

Comment: Ya,2009 you crystal pain still lives in 2013! man i realize now!!!!

Comment: @Kalpak That's why we need multiple data set

Answer (score 0):

Well, seeing as you have already abstracted away the 3 databases into your dataset, why not just use the dataset as your datasource. You select the xsd and design your report. When you run the report, you populate the dataset in code and set it as the report's datasource.

Otherwise, you can add each table to the report (doesn't matter if they are in different database) and link them together in crystal.